# Bluetooth Connection Android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have a BluetoothChat  application code in android.
Please anybody help me to find which Bluetooth profile is used for chat.

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-bluetooth-connection-example/